# WP custom field value

Tags: html, wordpress, function, custom-fields

I try to format some products price using a custom field (unit_price). My value is 3.2 (3,2) but the code doesn't recognize comma or dot and it shows only 3
Is there any way I could achieve showing the full value?
Any help is appreciated.

```
function cw_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) 
{
$unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit_price', true );
if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
    $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' per kg</span>'; 
}

return $price_html;
}    
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_html', 10, 2 );


function cw_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) 
{
$unit_price = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'unit_price', true );
if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) 
{
$price = wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' per kg';   
}
return $price;} 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try dumping the output(just for better understanding the variable) from `$unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit_price', true );` as

> var_dump($unit_price);

This will return **string**. Then all you have to convert string into float

> $unit_price= floatval($unit_price);

Then you can use `wc_price( $unit_price )`.

Check documentation http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_price/ as **$price** is **float** value

Comment: Could you be more specific on how the code must look? Not quite a pro. Thank You!